# OnCheckedChanged event of Radio button is not firing inside the grid, Even after setting autopostback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ado.net

The UI:

```
<asp:RadioButton  GroupName="one"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListTwoIndexChanged"  Text='<%# Bind("ServiceName") %>' ID="rdbtn" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="RadiobuttonChecked"  AutoPostBack="true" onclick="checkRadioBtn1(this);"  />
```

.cs file

```
public void GrdService_DataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        RadioButton rd = e.Row.FindControl("rdbtn") as RadioButton;
        rd.CheckedChanged += this.RadiobuttonChecked;

    }

}
protected void RadiobuttonChecked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Entered Radio button");
}
```

And laoding Grid when it first request

Comment: Please don't tag spam, this question has nothing to do with `sql`

Comment: If you add events programatically, you need to do so again on every page load, including postback. So if you bind the grid inside an IsPostBack check, remove that.

Comment: Is this a single radio button? I would think a check box makes more sense. And if this is a RadioButton list in the gridview then you should at least show the markup of the template radio button list in that grid view. I don't want the whole markup for the gridview, but if this is a radio button list in a gridview, then you should at least show as such. I certainly have a solution for a radio button list inside of  gridview - but then again, I don't know if that's what you have right now.